# how to truncate table and set id with 1 default?

Tags: postgresql

After truncate table And  Insert any data but in table, table id in not started with 1

TRUNCATE  TABLE SOURCE;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your `id` column is defined as `identity` or `serial` use the [`restart identity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html#id-1.9.3.180.6) option:

```
truncate table source restart identity;
```